# Why does the LibSVM algorithm in Weka never stops with building?

Tags: classification, svm, weka, libsvm, grid-search

this is my first question on stackoverflow, so tell me if I'm not following the rules.

I'm using the Weka explorer in Windows 10 to classify some data. I'm trying to do some SVM with LibSVM, but I guess Weka get in a never ending loop during the building of the model. The attribute I'm trying to predict is the 'Body count'.

The training and dataset I use is of the following form (in .arff format):

```
@attribute 'Outdoor Temp' numeric
@attribute 'Body count' {0,1,2,3,4,5}
@attribute minute_of_the_day numeric
@attribute weekday {0,1,2,3,4,5,6}
@attribute weekend {0,1}
@attribute month numeric
@attribute quarter numeric
@attribute day_of_the_year numeric
@data
13.538111,0,705,1,0,12,4,356
13.645444,0,720,1,0,12,4,356
13.737778,0,735,1,0,12,4,356 
...
```

The training set has about 67831 samples, and test set has about 22727 samples.

To auto determine the cost and gamma property, I use GridSearch. So in GridSearch I use the default parameters, except for:

- XProperty: 'cost'
- YProperty: 'gamma'
- classifier: 'LibSVM'
- evaluation: 'Accuracy'

In LibSVM I leave all the parameters by their default value.
In these links, you can see all the [parameters of the GridSerach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8nOK.png) and [those from LibSVM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ng5Iv.png).

The memory information from Weka gives me 1,375,670,664/1,559,232,512/7,602,176,000 so I don't think that's the problem.

Can someone give me a hint about what's going wrong here?

If you need more information, pleas just ask. I have yet tried to run it with some less attributes, but it keeps running for hours and hours...

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the system you're using, but each line has 8 elements and there are 7 attributes defined.

Comment: @Reuben  That's a mistake in copying, I'll correct it in the question. My excuses. And the system I'm using is a Windows 10 laptop with i7 processor and 32 GB of ram.

Comment: Have you tried running it without GridSearch? What is the duration of a simple training with default parameters of LibSVM?

Comment: @xro7 When I run it without GridSearch and default parameters, it takes 6 minutes. I think that doesn't is extremely long, is it?

Comment: Well if GridSearch tries only 10 different parameters searches this makes an hour. I think GridSearch tries a lot more that 10 hence the super long time.

Comment: Hmm ok, that makes sense... I guess I'll have to try some parameters myself then.